# Dynamic snowflake jdbc connection in java

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to create a dynamic JDBC connection in java to connect to snowflake.

I am stuck at a point ,how can i pass the parameter from my property file into snowflake connection file

Please find the attached code

```
package com.cisco.export.utils;


import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.cisco.config.Configuration;



public class SFDbConnection {

    public Connection getConnection(Configuration config) throws SQLException{
        Connection connection=null;
        try {
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.driverclass"));
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.url"));
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.account"));
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.username"));
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.password"));
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.warehouse"));
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.db"));
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.schema"));
            System.out.println(config.getProp("sf.role"));




            Class.forName(config.getProp("sf.driverclass"));
            String connectStr = "jdbc:snowflake://mysnowflakeaccount.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com";
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection()


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

Can some one Help me how  can  i make the parameters inside the getConnection() dynamic.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake JDBC Driver accepts connection properties [via the connection-string](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#jdbc-driver-connection-string) or via a [`java.util.Properties` class object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Using the properties in a [connection string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```java
String sfAccount = config.getProp("sf.account");
String sfUsername = config.getProp("sf.username");
String sfPassword = config.getProp("sf.password");
String sfWarehouse = config.getProp("sf.warehouse");
String sfDatabase = config.getProp("sf.db");
String sfSchema = config.getProp("sf.schema");
String sfRole = config.getProp("sf.role");

String connectionString =
  String.format("jdbc:snowflake://%s.snowflakecomputing.com/?role=%s&warehouse=%s&db=%s&schema=%s",
    sfAccount,
    sfRole,
    sfWarehouse,
    sfDatabase,
    sfSchema
  );

return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, sfUsername, sfPassword);
```

The `com.cisco.config.Configuration` class is not a known public API type, but if it can be translated to a `java.util.Properties` object, you can pass it [when building a connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-). Here's a direct conversion:

```java
java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();

String connectionString =
  String.format(
    "jdbc:snowflake://%s.snowflakecomputing.com",
    config.getProp("sf.account")
  );

props.setProperty("user", config.getProp("sf.username"));
props.setProperty("password", config.getProp("sf.password"));
props.setProperty("role", config.getProp("sf.role"));
props.setProperty("warehouse", config.getProp("sf.warehouse"));
props.setProperty("db", config.getProp("sf.db"));
props.setProperty("schema", config.getProp("sf.schema"));

return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, props);
```